# stack divs with different heights to the left of the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the divs with different heights in my div structure. Each div contains `<p>` tags and `<h2>` tags. These are drawn using the data retrieved from the server side. I want to stack them to the left of the screen. the below example shows how it's displayed now.

[image]

What I want is to position all the divs left aligned irrelevant of the height and width of it. Sort of a left aligned stack.

The following is the div structure of the above image.

```
<div class="specials-container">
<div class="clear"></div>
<article class="facility-group">
    <h2>Accomodation</h2>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>2 Luxurious Rooms With Attached Toilets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Armchair &amp; built in window seat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>55 metres sq.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<article class="facility-group">
    <h2>Health</h2>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Double Vanity, Illuminated Makeup/Shaving Mirror</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Air Conditioned</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<article class="facility-group">
    <h2>Connectivity</h2>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>High Speed Internet Access</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>LCD Screen Television With Cable Channels</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<article class="facility-group">
    <h2>Special</h2>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>King Size Balinese Four Poster Double Bed or Large</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Family Suite consists of a Double Garden Suite.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<article class="facility-group">
    <h2>Common</h2>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Shared Bathroom</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Complimentary Toiletries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Express Check In</p>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-box">
        <img src="/clientImages/TheWallawwa/facility-tick.png">
        <p>Free News Paper</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS that I've applied. I've only added the parent CSS and the container CSS. Omitted the images and header CSS. If needed I'll post them too.

```
.specials-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

article {
    padding: 10px 6px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I tired the `display:flex` and other display commands. But those are not supported by older IE versions like IE 7.

here is the way I want to stack the DIVs.

[image]

Comment: so you want them to just stack one below the other on the left of the screen?

Comment: I've added an image of the way I want to stack the divs!

Comment: you can use something like [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) although im not sure of its support for older versions of IE

Comment: Unfortunately it's only for personal use! :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this matter using the `clear` command. If I use a clear-fix for every fourth element which I draw, the elements get stacked to the left.

in this case, I've to add `clear:left` to each fourth element I draw.